# Is there a way to run upgrade.php for one blog?

Tags: multisite, database, upgrade, network-admin

I just ran the auto update to verion 3.9 today, but am having problems with the "Network Update".

I seem to have a firewall or network problem with this error :

> Your server may not be able to connect to sites running on it. Error
>   message: couldn't connect to host

Anyways, is there a way to run the database updates per blog ?  Can I use a special URL ?  Can I do it from shell command line ?

On an old forum post, someone suggested that update.php runs automatically the first time you log into your blog admin ( even if Network Update hasn't been run ).  I wonder if that's true.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP CLI has a command that can upgrade the database:

```
wp core update-db
```

If that command doesn't upgrade the entire network, you can pass in the site you want upgraded as an additional parameter

e.g.

```
wp core update-db --site="http://example.com/testsite/"
```

You can get WP CLI from here:

http://wp-cli.org

it's also available on github

You can install using:

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar > wp-cli.phar
```

It also comes with VVV

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I installed wp-cli and wrote a shell script to update all 300 blogs.  It worked great.  Thanks